# Substring, Charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to extract a code that varies in length that exists after the first two underscores and before the third underscore in a field in a table. The table looks something like this. There are greater than 30 codes and I need to extract the code as part of a query.

```
code
====
XX_YYY_CODE1_ZZZ
XX_YYY_CODE2_ZZZ
XX_YYY_CODE3_ZZZ
XX_YYY_CODE4_ZZZ
...
```

I've tried using this code however this gives me YYY rather than the CODE I'm after and I can't work out how to re-engineer it to do what I want it to do.

```
select 
left(SUBSTRING(code, 
CHARINDEX('_', code) + 1, len(code)), 
CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(code,CHARINDEX('_', code) + 2, LEN(code))))
```

Comment: ,What is your expected output.?

Comment: Do all values have three underscores?  Can you provide better data samples? Because with all the same length, `substring()` is much simpler.

Comment: Apologies for slight lack of clarity in what I was looking for. There are the same number of underscores each time and 20-30 codes that vary in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING
(code, 
  CHARINDEX('_', code, CHARINDEX('_', code) + 1) + 1, 
  LEN(code) - 
  (CHARINDEX('_', code, CHARINDEX('_', code) + 1) + 1) -
  CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(code))
)
```

Comment: Thanks dotNET I've modified this slightly to get what was needed.

Comment: @MikeR: Glad to hear. Mark this as answer to help future readers if you think this answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

if only four underscore,Use below code

```
select parsename(replace('1_2_3_4','_','.'),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,I hope it is give your expected result :

```
 CREATE TABLE #Table(GvnString VARCHAR(100))

 INSERT INTO #Table( GvnString )
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code1_ZZZ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code2_ZZZ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code3_ZZZ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code4_ZZZ' 

 SELECT SUBSTRING(GvnString, CHARINDEX('_', GvnString, CHARINDEX('_', 
        GvnString) + 1) + 1, LEN(GvnString) - CHARINDEX('_', GvnString, 
        CHARINDEX('_', GvnString) + 1))
 FROM #Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reversing the string and doing the substring operation.

```
 CREATE TABLE #MyTable(Code VARCHAR(50))

 INSERT INTO #MyTable( Code)
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code1_ZZZ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code2_ZZZ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code3_ZZZ' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'XX_YYY_Code4_ZZZ' 

select Reverse(Substring
(substring (Reverse(code),charindex('_',Reverse(code))+1,Len(code)),0,
CHARINDEX('_',substring (Reverse(code),charindex('_',Reverse(code))+1,Len(code)))))
from #Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your code. It should work.

```
select 
SUBSTRING(
substring(substring(code,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code))
,CHARINDEX('_', substring(code
,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code)))+1
,len(code)),1,
LEN(substring(substring(code,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code))
,CHARINDEX('_', substring(code
,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code)))+1
,len(code)))
- len(substring(substring(substring(code,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code))
,CHARINDEX('_', substring(code
,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code)))+1
,len(code)),CHARINDEX('_', substring(substring(code,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code))
,CHARINDEX('_', substring(code
,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code)))+1
,len(code)))+1,
LEN(substring(substring(code,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code))
,CHARINDEX('_', substring(code
,CHARINDEX('_', code)+1,len(code)))+1
,len(code)))))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified answer from dotNET does what I needed. Examples below;

```
SELECT SUBSTRING
('XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ', 
  CHARINDEX('_', 'XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ', CHARINDEX
  ('_', 'XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ') + 1) + 1, 
  LEN('XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ') - 
  (CHARINDEX('_', 'XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ', CHARINDEX   
  ('_', 'XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ') + 1)) -
  CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE('XX_YYY_LongCode_ZZZ'))
)
```

Or another example

```
SELECT SUBSTRING
('XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ', 
  CHARINDEX('_', 'XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ', CHARINDEX    
  ('_', 'XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ') + 1) + 1, 
  LEN('XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ') - 
  (CHARINDEX('_', 'XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ', CHARINDEX 
  ('_', 'XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ') + 1)) -
  CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE('XX_YYY_otherCode_ZZZ'))
)
```